# Split string in dataframe by symbol in R

Tags: r, string, strsplit

lets say that I have this dataframe

```
df <- read.table(text="
              id date       paid_at    binded_at  
1            107 2016-12-16 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
2            107 2017-11-27 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
3            107 2017-11-28 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
4            109 2016-11-28 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
5            109 2017-11-29 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
6            110 2017-12-04 2018-01-01 2017-06-07", header=TRUE)
```

I´d like to split date with symbol `-` So each row should look like this `2016 12 16` I created this code

```
test <- df %>%
    mutate(date = strsplit(date, "-"))
```

Which gives me `c("2016", "12", "16")`

Comment: `cbind(df[-2],date=read.table(text=as.character(df$date),sep="-"))?`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `separate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   separate(date, into = c("year", "month", "day"), convert = TRUE)
```

NOTE: If we need the original column 'date' to be kept, change the default `remove = TRUE` to `remove = FALSE` in `separate`